# Could the last column stop breaking words with a long user name in the review queue history?

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

Long user name breaks the last column of the [review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history) (at least the Triage one, but this might relate to all of them):

[image]

It doesn't look good. Could we avoid the last column to break the words or shorten the display name e.g. by ellipsis? All the question titles were fully displayed (and had an extra space behind) on my screen, just that last column decided to break the words.

I got this in Chrome 39.0.2171.71 m on Windows if it matters.

---

<sup>P.S. for those looking at the history at this time, this screenshot I took in the afternoon (UTC 2014-12-08 13:09:18), so it's now deeper in the history...</sup>

Comment: Suspend the user. Nuke the account. Problem solved.

Comment: Get a wider monitor. Problem solved.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion, that won't help (at least not for Chrome browser). I can resize the browser window to more than 3840 pixels (on 2 monitors), but that column remains fixed. For wider monitors I don't have enough space on my table. Well, maybe a wider table with wider (and more) monitors.

Comment: Ok, then Bart's solution is better. Nuke all the users who have longer names ;)

Comment: Tangentially related from MSE: [Provide an ellipsis after a long name instead of truncating it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244729/213963) - though the problem here is it isn't getting truncated either.

Comment: What are people with long user names thinking alway?!

Answer (score 19):

We should truncate by ellipsis long u...

<kbd>We should truncate by ellipsis long usernames.  In a tooltip, we can print the full username in all its glory.</kbd>

Comment: [We should truncate by ellipsis long u...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278762/3991344 "We should truncate by ellipsis long usernames. In a tooltip, we can print the full username in all its glory.")

Comment: @Pokechu22 That's what I s...

Comment: I actually put a tooltip on that text as an example (markdown tooltips are in the form of `[text](url "Tooltip")`.

Comment: @Pokechu22 [All right, I'll p...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278762/1707091 "All right, I'll play along!")

Comment: [You guys are the w...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278731/could-the-last-column-stop-breaking-words-with-a-long-user-name-in-the-review-qu/278762#278762 "You guys are the win")

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick CSS fix:

```css
.history-table td:first-of-type a[href^="/users/"] {
    display: block;
    max-width: 150px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

This will cause long usernames to wrap onto multiple lines, instead of expanding at the expense of the other columns.<sup><sub>1</sub></sup>  Here's a screenshot demonstrating how it would look:

[image: Screenshot]

Just to be really sure, it might also be a good idea to stop the last two columns from wrapping entirely, e.g. with:

```css
.history-table a[href^="/review/"], .history-table .history-date {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This should ensure that very long post titles cannot cause a similar problem either.

<sup>1) The weird selector is because the table cells don't have class names to identify them; ideally, that would also be fixed.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the proposal (even though I have no idea what you've proposed since I'm not a web developer :)! However, in case which I've reported it would have been enough to stop just the last column from wrapping since the middle one had even some extra space for all the rows.